# Merge Conflicts in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2010, is it possible to send an email notification to the developers when there is a conflicts when we merge from branch to main?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? Why not just fix the merge conflicts, or at worst, go yell at the developer who caused the conflicts?

Comment: @JohnSaunders That's the way I solve my merge conflicts. Face to Face is the only way I can figure some of them out.

Comment: It's the only way to fix them. The way to reduce the number of them would be to institute Continuous Integration, and frequent check-in to a "Development" branch.

Comment: Please check if this post is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923084/tfs-2010-merge-changesets/8926886#8926886 .
It involves resorting to a self-made console app, so you 'd have to use this utility instead of tf or the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

No. The TFS Alerting model doesn't have support for client side events. A merge conflict is a client side event. You might be able to develop a plugin for Visual Studio to detect Conflict events, but then figuring out the list of users involved in each conflict would be a very complicated task.

Comment: Indeed it would - you could combine an annotation engine (I don't think TFS's is publicly exposed) with an automerge engine (again, I don't think Visual Studio's/TFS's is publicly exposed) to determine blame for a conflict.  But this is a whole lot of work for something that is of questionable value.